# P2V (Physical to Virtual) conversion for Veritas Cluster

Tags: vmware-vsphere, physical-to-virtual, veritas-cluster-server

We are having situation where we have 5 nodes app server in a cluster using Veritas Cluster. The Operating System are RHEL 6.6 and all are physical server (blade server)

We want to migrate all these 5 nodes app server to new data center, which is separated 50 KM from old data center.

There are 20 Gbps MPLS connectivity between two data centers

We are assessing 2 migration scenarios as follow:

1) P2V conversion using VMWare Converter or Platespin Migrate 
2) If it can't be P2Ved then we will do Lift and Shift with Storage Replication since it is connect to shared storage

Our questions are:
1) Is it possible to P2V Veritas Cluster nodes using VMWare Converter or Platespin Migrate? If yes, do we still need to reconfig the cluster? please also help to point us to any documentations or technical paper on how to do this without messing up the cluster configuration

2) All 5 nodes app servers once migrated using Lift and Shift to new Data Center will connect to new Storage, do we need to reconfigure the Veritas Cluster to connect with this new storage? or will it seamlessly work? If it needs reconfiguration, to what level is reconfiguration? do we need to reconfigure from scratch or just minor reconfiguration?

That's all our questions

Highly appreciate help from all of you for this

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to P2V with vCenter Converter. I'd suggest installing the Converter on your vCenter server or a dedicated server and use it as the workhorse.

In vCenter Converter, you'll be able to edit what goes to the new VM and can change the IP to match the destination network.

[This guide](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/convsa_60_guide.pdf) should also help. Reply if you need more info.